# Does `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE textfield >= "whatever";` return more than `count("whatever")` rows because it's an array?

Tags: mysql, types, operators, sql

I'm just wondering why

```
CREATE TABLE employeeinfo(
  position CHAR(50),
  salary INT NOT NULL,
  branch CHAR(50)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEEINFO
WHERE position >= 'Regional Manager';
```

is returning every person in the table.

Is it because it's some kind of array?  It's not an alphabetical thing.  Could it be because of the values in memory being greater than Regional Manager's value in memory?  I think someone told me it was because of a difference between pointer locations in memory?

Comment: Is it because _what_ is "some kind of array"? You should tell us what different result you expected, and why you expected it. Odds are you misunderstood `>=` on strings.

Comment: The [sample code](http://sscce.org/) isn't complete. What's the schema (i.e. `CREATE TABLE` statement) for table EMPLOYEEINFO?

Comment: @Tomalak I expected an error.  Something like NAN.  I thought maybe if there were an index it would return the proceeding values in the index array, though.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: _Why_ did you expect an error? And NaN is not an error. Why do you think there's an array somewhere? You need to _explain_ your thinking and reasoning because it is you, not MySQL, that is wrong here, and we can't tell how yet because you have not explained your thinking. You also haven't shown us the data you're comparing against.

Comment: @outis I think the answerers understood the question from the context.  I guess something like `CREATE TABLE employeeinfo(position CHAR(50), salary INT NOT NULL, branch CHAR(50)) ENGINE=InnoDB;`

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: we sort of understand, but my answer is still guesswork. Please edit the requested information into the question rather than replying via comments. Questions and answers shouldn't require visitors to read the comments in order to understand them. Comments aren't meant as a vehicle for discussion.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: That the answerers made a guess doesn't make the question any less broken. We expect you to formulate a coherent question and, if nothing else, analysing computing problems _precisely_ is a skill that you're going to need as you progress in your career.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: for more on the topic of stating a question well, read ["Writing the Perfect Question"](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and ["How To Ask Questions The Smart Way"](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: @Otis.  Alright, cool.  Thanks.  There's no "smart way" to ask a question, though.  I've seen those guides, and they were always a bad idea.  They're more of an excuse for people to publish unclear material that require answers (or rather "smart questions") for understanding, IMO.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: speaking from years of experience, I must disagree.

Comment: @otis Well, the endless river of poorly written documentation is the unstoppable force to your immovable opinion.

Comment: @Tomalak Your expectation is completely unreasonable.  A person who is untrained in a subject can't know the correct question until he knows the correct answer.  For example, in climbing, you can't expect a layman to ask an expert if his carabiner is locking or non-locking.  If the layman asks that, he's just got some other background by chance.  This is completely analogous, IMO, and I challenge you to show me any flaw in my understanding.  It's common knowledge in the teaching profession, but ridiculously denied by programmers for some reason.  Really, it's set in stone.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: not to belabor the point, but those guides are about much more than reading the documentation. Jon Skeet's article in particular barely mentions searching for existing information; if you haven't seen this, perhaps it's time for a second look. It's not only possible to understand a problem (which is what it takes to properly ask questions about it) without foreknowledge of solutions, it's an essential skill (some would say *the* essential skill) in development. While this ability isn't often innate, it can be learned. You're obviously a smart person; use that intelligence.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5278/discussion-between-outis-and-wolfpack08)

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: Just because you don't know the subject well doesn't mean you are unable to provide all pertinent information about your testcase, and it doesn't mean that saying "X happens" without explaining what _different_ things you expected to happen is going to help anyone. That's nothing to do with the subject matter: it's basic problem specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as an array in relational databases.

If the statement is returning every entry, it's because the condition always evaluates to true. This implies that `position` is always >= the string 'Regional Manager', so the task is to determine why this is the case.

If `position` has a text type, then the comparison is a string comparison, so something such as 'S' would be >= 'Regional Manager'. String comparisons depend on the [encoding](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset.html) (called "character set" in MySQL parlance) and [collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-general.html) used for the column. The collation determines the order for individual characters. Additionally, MySQL uses [case insensitive comparisons](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case-sensitivity.html) by default for most collations, so `'a' < 'Regional Manager'` but `'s' >= 'Regional Manager'`.

If `position` holds a numeric value, then MySQL will [convert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html) 'Regional Manager' to a number using as much as the beginning of the string as can be interpreted as a number:

```
SELECT CAST( 'Regional Manager' AS SIGNED INT );
-- result: 0
SELECT CAST( '23 Skidoo' AS SIGNED INT );
-- result: 23
```

If this is the case, then as long as `position` is positive, it will be >= 'Regional Manager'.

Comment: So, you're basically saying it is alphabetical, and I wasn't able to see that.  That could be the case.  Thank you.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: This behaviour is quite explicitly discussed in the MySQL manual.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm still getting familiar with the manual.  I guess I'll reference the "Behavioral MySQL" section before I get curious, in the future.  As a clear expert, I can easily extrapolate the page number from your useful comment. lol

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: my answer links to most (if not all) the relevant sections. As for any others, does your expertise not extend to web searches?

Comment: @outis It doesn't always extend to the vocabulary necessary to pull the appropriate result from a web search.  I guess you could have thrown some keywords out and gotten the green check mark, if you knew a good google result set.  Of course, educators should never assume that their learners have any of the required skill set beyond elementary education (assuming they're not teaching elementary school kids).  You probably know from years of experience that google is a foreign concept to some people studying beginner's C.  I  have about a 1.5 week combined background in MySQL.  I'm non-Native.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: "web search" doesn't mean "google". The MySQL site and manual have their own search functions, for example. An important (and basic) skill for any developer is to learn how to access the documentation. Fair enough point about not knowing what keywords to use, but (when that's the case) you can always include it in your problem description.

Comment: @outis Alright, well thanks for the answer and the references, again.  It's really nice of you to help.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: You don't need to extrapolate the single page number. You need to read the _whole_ manual, especially since you're new to MySQL, and that you haven't done that already as a matter of course is cause for concern. When you buy a new Boeing 777 do you just jump in and start the engines, without reading through the instruction manual?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Let's take a look at the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html.  Show me where the table creation code is, please.  I think they're leading by example.  Leading us to failure, that is.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: No, you're right in saying that the MySQL manual doesn't have a section dedicated to the exact query that _you_ want to write today. What it _does_ cover, is all the points mentioned in this answer (and the author even provided all the links to his references)... an answer which you found helpful.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal But this reflects the poor standard of writing that exists throughout the MySQL manual.   It's not only the above-mentioned page, but every page in the manual that is severely lacking. When the writers of the manual don't even hold to the basic quality standards you reference, how do you expect anyone to take them seriously?  The manual isn't worthy of referencing, let alone reading cover-to-cover, and the people who have the knowledge to correct it are picking on noob programmers: "Ask better questions," rather than making effective corrections that would help everyone.

Comment: If I'd had the privilege to be educated at the level of the people to whom I'm paying these questions, I'd certainly feel an obligation to give back by correcting whatever pages of the manuals I could.  More than just the page I'm trying to understand today: every single page of the manual should be invariably without flaw.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: how is § 12.2.9.6 relevant? What standards? What do you mean by "paying"? SO and the MySQL manual are free-of-charge. As for "picking on noob[s]", knowing how to write questions well involves skills essential for developers; someone who can't break a problem down properly will have a terrible time of it creating a solution. Moreover, giving advice about asking questions doesn't preclude anyone from writing (or improving) manuals.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5278/discussion-between-outis-and-wolfpack08)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: that includes you.

Comment: @outis: I have no interest in continuing this ridiculous conversation.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: fair enough. It does seem rather unprofitable.